# GWT UiBinder CellTable is not rendered with AsyncDataProvider

Tags: gwt, uibinder, celltable

I want to have on my page created with `UIBinder` a `CellTable` with data, received from server.
I think I dont quite understand the logic of `UiBinder`. What steps should I do before calling `initWidget()`, and what I shouldn't  ? 
 When I remove the call to `configureDataProvider()` the table appears, but it is empty, with progress bar running. When I include `configureDataProvider()`, the table is not rendered at all.

**Please can you explain what is happening here?**

```java
@UiField(provided = true)
VerticalPanel tableSelection;

@UiField(provided = true)
Anchor productTableAnchor;

@UiField(provided = true)
Anchor ordersTableAnchor;

@UiField(provided = true)
Anchor staffTableAnchor;
List<ProductDTO> products;

@UiField(provided = true)
CellTable<ProductDTO> productTable;

@UiField(provided = true)
SimplePager pager;

public TableSelectionWidget() {
SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT
    .create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
tableSelection = new VerticalPanel();
productTableAnchor = new Anchor();
ordersTableAnchor = new Anchor();
staffTableAnchor = new Anchor();
productTable = new CellTable<ProductDTO>();
productTable.setPageSize(10);
configureTable();
pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, false, 0,
    true);
pager.setDisplay(productTable);
initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}

private void configureTable() {
Column<ProductDTO, String> nameColumn = new Column<ProductDTO, String>(
    new TextCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ProductDTO object) {
    return object.getName();
    }
};
Column<ProductDTO, String> priceColumn = new Column<ProductDTO, String>(
    new TextCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ProductDTO object) {
    return object.getPrice().toString();
    }
};
Column<ProductDTO, String> quantityColumn = new Column<ProductDTO, String>(
    new TextCell()) {
    @Override
    public String getValue(ProductDTO object) {
    return String.valueOf(object.getQuantity());
    }
};
productTable.addColumn(nameColumn, "Name");
productTable.addColumn(priceColumn, "Price");
productTable.addColumn(quantityColumn, "Qty");

configureDataProvider();

}

private void configureDataProvider() {
AsyncDataProvider<ProductDTO> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<ProductDTO>() {
    @Override
    protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<ProductDTO> display) {
    final int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
    int length = display.getVisibleRange().getLength();
    AsyncCallback<List<ProductDTO>> callback = new AsyncCallback<List<ProductDTO>>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
        }

        public void onSuccess(List<ProductDTO> result) {
        products = result;
        updateRowData(start, result);
        }
    };

    productService.getAllProducts(callback);
    }
};

provider.addDataDisplay(productTable);
provider.updateRowCount(products.size(), true);
}
```

EDIT Added ui.xml

```
    <!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui" xmlns:c="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client"
    xmlns:ct="urn:import:com.ooo1sk.client.widgets">
    <ui:style>
    </ui:style>
    <g:HTMLPanel>
        <g:VerticalPanel styleName="" ui:field="tableSelection">
            <g:Anchor ui:field="ordersTableAnchor" text="Orders"></g:Anchor>
            <g:Anchor ui:field="productTableAnchor" text="Product"></g:Anchor>
            <g:Anchor ui:field="staffTableAnchor" text="Staff"></g:Anchor>
        </g:VerticalPanel>
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='width:100%;'>
                <tr>
                    <td valign='top'>
                        <c:CellTable addStyleNames='infoTable' pageSize='15'
                            ui:field='productTable' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'>
                        <c:SimplePager ui:field='pager' />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

UPD: after changes it works, but keeps showing me only the first 15 rows, however Pager shows all 91 rows and changes number after clicking.

```
 private void configureDataProvider() {

    AsyncDataProvider<ProductDTO> provider = new AsyncDataProvider<ProductDTO>() {
        @Override
        protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<ProductDTO> display) {
        final int start = display.getVisibleRange().getStart();
        final int length = display.getVisibleRange().getLength();
   
        productService
            .getAllProducts(new AsyncCallback<List<ProductDTO>>() {

                public void onSuccess(List<ProductDTO> result) {
                label.setText("start " + start + " "
                    + "resultsize " + result.size() + " "
                    + "length " + length);
                products = result;
                updateRowCount(result.size(), true);
                updateRowData(start, result);

                }

                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                Window.alert(caught.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    };
    provider.addDataDisplay(productTable);
    }
```

Ok, playing with numbers fixed the issue. in `updateRowData(start, result);` I changed `start` to `0` and it works fine now. Still, I would greatly appreciate any comment of experts on this.

Comment: Please include the UiBinder source file (`TableSelectionWidget.ui.xml`). Why are you creating all of the widgets in code, instead of using the UiBinder XML file to create them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`initWidget(Widget widget)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html#initWidget%28com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget%29) is a method of the [`Composite`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Composite.html) class used to initialize itself as a wrapper for a possible inner aggregation of widgets. Generally you create a composition of widgets rooted on a given widget and then pass it to the `initiWidget()` method. This way, the rooted element is not exposed (in terms of its methods) but still acts as if it was never wrapped.

In your sample you have `UiBinder` takes care of defining the UI, so you pass to such method the return of the binding creation (`uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this)`). Before this call (actually, before the `createAndBindUi()`, but generally it is tied to the `initWidget()`), you *must* instantiate all your widget marked with `@UiField(provided = true)` i.e., all those who need a proper initialization otherwise impossible in plain `UiBinder` style. In your case, you don't need to mark everything `provided = true`, only the `CellTable` requires that (for the specialization).

Back to your problem, if you remove the `configureDataProvider()` call, you will never set up the `AsyncDataProvider` and simply you will see no data at all (the spinning gif is because somewhere - can't remember where now - the row count has been set to 0). If you enable it, the call to `addDataDisplay()` will implicitly force a range update that will end up calling the `AsyncDataProvider` to request your data.

The problem is that you do not update both the row data *and* the row count at the same time in the `onSuccess()` callback. See [here](http://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/gwt-2-2-asyncdataprovider-celltable-gotcha/).

Also, you don't need to call `updateRowCount()` after `addDataDisplay()`, otherwise two requests will be made to retrieve the same initial data, which is unnecessary.

Comment: Do I also have to configure widgets (that is, add label to Button, columns to Table) before calling `initWidget()` ?

Comment: No, the structure (adding this to that) is defined by the nesting of widgets in the `UiBinder` XML definition. After that you can very well set styles, properties and so on on every widget you've defined. But probably you would do yourself a favor and use `UiBinder` as much as possible, for styles, texts and the like. See [here](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder) for all the details.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but another issue appeared. Please look into updated question.